# Some sites won't load on Ubuntu/Mint

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-mint

I have a REALLY weird problem with either my network or my OS.

Last week I've suddenly had difficulties loading **some** websites or even more odd **some parts** of different websites. For example, I could load gmail.com, login and view the list of emails in my inbox but when I clicked one of them it would just time out. Another example is http://www.ynet.co.il, I can view the home page but going into any one of the articles fails (times out).

I've tried Chrome, Firefox and Opera, all fail the same way.

If I take a URL of a page I cannot load via the browser and try to `wget` it though the console I get the file just fine.

I've formatted my machine (Used to run Ubuntu 13.04) and installed Mint Linux this time, it worked fine for a few days and now, again, having the same exact issues.

Important to note that I have other machines connected either directly or via Wi-Fi to the router and they are all working fine (two win7 machines and 1 raspberry pi).

Another strange behavior is that I can ftp or ssh to remote machines but cannot send files via ftp (times out) even if I set passive mode ON and when using ssh I can do just about anything but I cannot paste text into the remote machine, for example if I `nano` a file on the remote machine and try to paste anything from my clipboard it freezes.

**What I've tried so far:**

1. Disable IPv6 on the networking admin (and on firefox disabling ipv6 on the about:config page)
2. Changing the port and the network cable
3. I went to the store and bought a new standalone PCIe network adapter
4. Connected my win7 laptop using the same cable and router port (sites that were not working on my Mint are working just fine on the win7 machine)
5. Loaded Mint from a livecd, got the same result
6. Tried changing the MTU (was 1500, tried 1492)

**Some observations:**

1. When I clear my browser cache and go to facebook.com for example, the homepage loads but I fail to load any profile/group page. If I refresh facebook.com homepage a couple of times it stops and fails to load until I clear my browser cache. I changed the chrome cache folder permissions to `0777` but that did not help.
2. When I run `netstat -n` I see **A LOT** of connections that are in 'FIN_WAIT' mode (I'm guessing that's when I try to refresh pages that are not working and timing out), I have no idea what it means or if it helps anyone figure out what's wrong.
3. The sites that are not loading correctly are always that same, they don't vary or anything and they fail to load exactly the same way on all three browsers that I've tried.
4. When I Googled 'Ubuntu some sites not loading' I see a huge amount of complaints just like mine, but none of them that I could find actually says what the problem is or how they fixed it.

**Technical stuff:**

1. [netstat -n](http://pastebin.com/VhNv3ZAa)
2. [ps aux](http://pastebin.com/waaEwC9A)
3. [netstat -nr](http://pastebin.com/wSKbcDGD)

Comment: "I've formatted my machine (Used to run Ubuntu 13.04) and installed Mint Linux this time, it worked fine for a few days and now, again, having the same exact issues." What have you changed or added since you installed the OS? The fact that wget works but browsers do not lends itself to a software conflict or plugin issue, not an underlying OS or network connectivity issue.

Comment: I am also wondering why you seemed to just "randomly" change your MTU size? It is not uncommon for DSL to need a smaller MTU size than 1500, although it is usually done at the router level, but have you tested it? It is pretty simple to do with ping.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue on Ubuntu 20.04. I had two default routes, one via wifi and one via the ethernet. The ethernet route had a lower metric:

```
me@UBU20:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         x.x.x 0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enx9cebe8eb937c
default         x.x.x 0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
...
```

When I disabled wifi, everything loaded fine. I suspect my issue was caused by my wifi driver (which I knew was faulty). So disabling wifi fixed my issue.